# Raydium CLLM pool not showing up after 4 days

Tags: solana, solana-web3js

I created a sample CLLM liquidity pool on Raydium 4 days ago. It still does not show up in "My Pools" page and I can not trade the tokens. However, the transaction says it was succeeded and the tokens were deducted from my wallet.

Here is the transaction details on the pool creation:

https://solscan.io/tx/3YscytA6LmYXhFC3ZWMVz1MLA5zXnSadhootethemtf1hw9Ep5GRUJ5tCohzzGZUeWxamGm13mTeKt8fBfAHvrCw

https://solscan.io/tx/2Y4DaxbiepfoMy8dYoNV5pPsv7KRzVNsD5GqTWad8cto1EZ2HNTvmD4pgRkE6JLpCnYxj7wZeB7HLzKVH1A4VCwD